# Setting up a new project with typescript, react and jest and I am running into a SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am setting up  a new project from scratch. The project is in typescript using storybooks and jest for testing. I am encountering an issue while running `toMatchSnapshot()` assertion on a react component.

This is my `index.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import {Button} from '../index';

it('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<Button/>).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

My `jest.config.ts`:

```
import type {Config} from '@jest/types';

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
    verbose: true,
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        'src/components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    ],
    coverageDirectory: 'reports/coverage/unit',
    coverageThreshold: {
        global: {
            branches: 90,
            functions: 90,
            lines: 90,
            statements: 90,
        },
    },
    transform: {'^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest'},
    testMatch: ['**/*.test.*'],
    coverageProvider: 'v8',
};

export default config;
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "type-check": "tsc",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext .tsx",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "test:coverage": "npm run test -- --coverage",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@storybook/react": "^6.3.7",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "storybook-addon-responsive-views": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.3.7",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.3.7",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.3.7",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.3.7",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.3.7",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.3.7",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.6.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.2",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.1",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "node-sass-magic-importer": "^5.3.2",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run lint"
    }
  }
}
```

When I run my test this is the result:

```
 FAIL  src/components/buttons/button/__tests__/index.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Users/marco/Code/project-name/src/components/buttons/button/__tests__/index.test.tsx:19
        const tree = react_test_renderer_1.default.create(<index_1.Button />).toJSON();
                                                          ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1479:14)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.003 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is very simple.I had to set the "jsx" key to "react" rather than "preserve" in tsconfig.json.
Found the answer here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8663